how to update SharePoint library file meta data in Power Apps
I have a Document library named "Project Details" with different files and folders with different columns. I have also added some files inside folders, like the one below.

Now, I would like to update the specific file inside the folder using my Power Apps Form. For that, I have used the below code.
Patch(
'Project Details',
First(
    Filter(
        'Project Details',
        gal_Records.Selected.ID
    )
),
{
    'First Name': DataCardValue2.Text,
    'Last Name': DataCardValue3.Text,
    Email: DataCardValue4.Text,
    'Document Type': {Value: DataCardValue10.Selected.Value},
    'Project Details': DataCardValue5.Text,
    'Start Date': DataCardValue6.SelectedDate,
    'End Date': DataCardValue7.SelectedDate,
    ' Is Approved': DataCardValue9.Value
}

)

But, unfortunately, it will update the main folder records. However, my requirement is to update specific file metadata. Could please give any solution

the First and Filter functions are not required here. Try this code:
Patch(
    'Project Details',
    gal_Records.Selected,
    {...}
)

